# Set Up an AppSpot sub-domain to point to ANOTHER AppSpot app

Tags: google-app-engine, dns, subdomain

So, I have two separate AppEngine projects with two separate App ID's. Ideally, I'd like to a subdomain on app1 to point to app2.

In other words, my apps are: `app1.appspot.com` and `app2.appspot.com`, and I'd like to set it up so that: `app2.app1.appspot.com` points its DNS to `app2.appspot.com`.

First off, is this possible? If so, how do I do it?

Also, if it's possible, does this violate the ToS set by AppEngine? Notably this clause:

> 4.4. You may not develop multiple Applications to simulate or act as a single Application or otherwise access the Service in a manner intended to avoid incurring fees.

**NOTE:** This is all required for business organization reasons ***far*** outside my control. Using a custom domain, like `app2.app.com` and `app1.app.com` is not a solution we can pursue.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This DOES look iffy on the ToS side.....

Comment: Although technically possible, I agree it could easily be considered a violation of the ToS.

Comment: Yea, the ToS is what is scaring me and preventing me from doing this... I think it's a pretty clear violation. Thanks for confirming my assumptions guys! If anyone interprets that differently, please do comment.